# Get rank of matrix entries?

Tags: r, matrix, rank

Assume a matrix:

```
> a <- matrix(c(100, 90, 80, 20), 2, 2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  100   80
[2,]   90   20
```

Suppose I want to convert the elements of the matrix to ranks:

```
>rank.a <- rank(a)
> rank.a
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

This returns a vector, i.e. the matrix structure is lost. Is it possible to rank a matrix such that the output will be of the form:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   4    2 
[2,]   3    1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to @EDi's Answer is to copy `a` and then assign the output of `rank(a)` directly into the elements of the copy of `a`:

```
> a <- matrix(c(100, 90, 80, 20), 2, 2)
> rank.a <- a
> rank.a[] <- rank(a)
> rank.a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    3    1
```

That saves you from rebuilding a matrix by interrogating the dimensions of the input matrix.

Note that (as @Andrie mentions in the comments) the copying of `a` is only required if one wants to keep the original `a`. The main point to note is that because `a` is already of the appropriate dimensions, we can treat it like a vector and replace the contents of `a` with the vector of ranks of `a`.

Comment: +1 Very nice.  Your answer lead me to experiment - it seems it's not necessary to create the copy. `a[] <- rank(a)` does the trick.  This idiom is going straight into my list of useful things to do in R.

Comment: @Andrie I just presumed the OP might want `a` left alone - you are quite right that there is no need to copy the matrix if `a` can be thrown away.

Answer (score 3):

why not convert the vector back to a matrix, with the dimensions of the original matrix?

```
> a <- matrix(c(100, 90, 80, 20, 10, 5), 2, 3)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  100   80   10
[2,]   90   20    5
> rank(a)
[1] 6 5 4 3 2 1
> rmat <- matrix(rank(a), nrow = dim(a)[1], ncol = dim(a)[2])
> rmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    4    2
[2,]    5    3    1
```

Answer (score 3):

@Gavin Simpson has a very nice and elegant solution! But there is one caveat though:

The type of the matrix will stay the same or be widened. Mostly you wouldn't notice, but consider the following:

```
a <- matrix( sample(letters, 4), 2, 2)
rank.a <- a
rank.a[] <- rank(a)
typeof(rank.a) # character
```

Since the matrix was character to start with, the `rank` values (which are doubles) got coerced into  character strings!

Here's a safer way that simply copies all the attributes:

```
a <- matrix( sample(letters, 4), 2, 2)
rank.a <- rank(a)
attributes(rank.a) <- attributes(a)
typeof(rank.a) # double
```

Or, as a one-liner using `structure` to copy only the relevant attributes (but more typing):

```
a <- matrix( sample(letters, 4), 2, 2)
rank.a <- structure(rank(a), dim=dim(a), dimnames=dimnames(a))
```

Of course, `dimnames` could be left out in this particular case.