# Replacing each value in a vector with its rank number for a data.frame

Tags: r, ranking

In this hypothetical scenario, I have performed 5 different analyses on 13 chemicals, resulting in a score assigned to each chemical within each analysis. I have created a table as follows:

`----   Analysis1   Analysis2   Analysis3   Analysis4   Analysis5
Chem_1  3.524797844 4.477695034 4.524797844 4.524797844 4.096698498
Chem_2  2.827511555 3.827511555 3.248136118 3.827511555 3.234398548
Chem_3  2.682144761 3.474646298 3.017780505 3.682144761 3.236152242
Chem_4  2.134137304 2.596921333 2.95181339  2.649076603 2.472875191
Chem_5  2.367736454 3.027814219 2.743137896 3.271122346 2.796607809
Chem_6  2.293110565 2.917318708 2.724156207 3.293110565 2.530967343
Chem_7  2.475709113 3.105794018 2.708222528 3.475709113 3.088819908
Chem_8  2.013451822 2.259454085 2.683273938 2.723554966 2.400976121
Chem_9  2.345123123 3.050074893 2.682845391 3.291851228 2.700844104
Chem_10 2.327658894 2.848729452 2.580415233 3.327658894 2.881490893
Chem_11 2.411243882 2.98131398  2.554456095 3.411243882 3.109205453
Chem_12 2.340778276 2.576860244 2.549707035 3.340778276 3.236545826
Chem_13 2.394698249 2.90682524  2.542599327 3.394698249 3.12936843`

I would like to create columns corresponding to each analysis which contain the rank position for each chemical. For instance, under `Analysis1`,`Chem_1` would have value "1",  `Chem_2` would have value "2", `Chem_3` would have value "4", `Chem_7` would have value "4", `Chem_11` would have value "5", and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `dense_rank` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate_each(funs(dense_rank(-.)))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
df[] <- lapply(-df, rank, ties.method="min")
```

---

In `data.table`, we can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(-.SD, frank, ties.method="dense")]
```

To avoid the copies from multiplying with `-`, as @Arun mentioned in the comments

```
lapply(.SD, frankv, order=-1L, ties.method="dense")
```

Comment: `ties.method="min"` != dense rank. In data.table, there's `ties.method="dense"`.

Comment: Also, I'd do: `lapply(.SD, frankv, order=-1L, ties.method="dense")` which'll avoid the copy due to `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in base R:

```
cbind("..." = df[,1], data.frame(do.call(cbind, 
                                         lapply(df[,-1], order, decreasing = T))))

       ... Analysis1 Analysis2 Analysis3 Analysis4 Analysis5
1   Chem_1         1         1         1         1         1
2   Chem_2         2         2         2         2        12
3   Chem_3         3         3         3         3         3
4   Chem_4         7         7         4         7         2
5   Chem_5        11         9         5        11        13
6   Chem_6        13         5         6        13        11
7   Chem_7         5        11         7        12         7
8   Chem_8         9         6         8        10        10
9   Chem_9        12        13         9         6         5
10 Chem_10        10        10        10         9         9
11 Chem_11         6         4        11         5         6
12 Chem_12         4        12        12         8         4
13 Chem_13         8         8        13         4         8
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to have the column-wise rank of your table. Here is my solution:

```
m=data.matrix(df) # converts data frame to matrix, convert your data to matrix accordingly
apply(m, 2, function(c) rank(c)) # increasingly
apply(m, 2, function(c) rank(-c)) # decreasingly
```

However, I believe you could solve it by yourself with the help of the answers to this question
[Get rank of matrix entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610495/get-rank-of-matrix-entries)